# How is it possible that a plane with 4 engines can be less reliable than a plane with 2 engines?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a probability question which states that a plane must have at least half of its engines working to be functional. Each engine functions independently with a probability of p. For what values of p is the 4-engine plane more likely to operate than a 2-engine plane?

I don't need help solving the problem, I understand the logic behind it. I don't understand the result intuitively though and it's bothering me quite a bit. How is it possible that for a p >= 1/2, the 4-engine plane is less reliable than the 2-engine plane?

My (obviously flawed) logic goes as follows. If there are 4 engines on the plane, you need 3 to fail for the plane to fail. I can't understand how it's possible for it to be more likely that 3 engines fail on the 4-engine than 2 on the 2-engine. I'm sure there's some way of looking at the problem that I'm missing, but I'm not sure how I could frame the result to click in my head.

If anyone has any idea how to reframe these results in a more intuitive way, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You said you solved the problem and understand the logic. Can you show your work? Comparing your work with your intuition may help point out flaws in your intuition.

Comment: Added my work, sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Actually, I think the truth is that four engine plane is more reliable for $p > \frac23$ so your intuition that 4 is safer is correct given the likely values of $p$ in real life. If $p=0.99$, the two engine plane is 25 times more likely to crash.

Comment: Your algebra after the "..." is not correct, if you did it correctly there would have to be a $p^4$ and a $p^3$ term in there somewhere.

Comment: $4p(1-p)$ should be $4p(1-p)^3$. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/afsyhw38lo -- what you have for 4 engines is not even a probability for $p<.58$.

Comment: @DavidK, you're right thanks, I made a mistake copying one of my lines. My question does still stand though, I still don't really understand how it's possible for any value of p that 4 engines could be less reliable than 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the graphs of $1 - 4p(1-p) - (1-p)^4$, $1 - 4p(1-p) - (1-p)^4$ (which is the correct probability for a four-engine plane), and $1-(1-p)^2$.
(It says $x$ rather than $p$ since I plotted this on desmos.com, but the curves have the same shapes regardless of what variable is in the polynomials.)

[image]

It turns out that $1 - 4p(1-p) - (1-p)^4$ actually is less than $1-(1-p)^2$
for all $0 < p < 1$, not just for $p > 1/2$.

As for why the four-engine plane is less reliable when $p$ is small,
remember that the four-engine plane has to keep at least **two** engines running
while the two-engine plane only needs to keep one engine running.
In order for a two-engine plane to fail, $100$ percent of its engines must fail;
the four-engine plane fails if only $75$ percent of its engines fail.